# Hbase HRegionServer WARN and shutdown after a while

Tags: hbase

I had a little hadoop cluster(4 servers),and install with hbase,but it not work well.
after i tab 'start-hbase.sh',in 3 HRegionServer's log

> 2016-07-27 21:29:55,122 WARN  [ResponseProcessor for block BP-1601089490-xx.xx.xx.xx-1469276064635:blk_1073742337_1586] hdfs.DFSClient: DFSOutputStream ResponseProcessor exception  for block BP-1601089490-xx.xx.xx.xx-1469276064635:blk_1073742337_1586
>   java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.vintPrefixed(PBHelper.java:2000)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:176)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DFSOutputStream.java:798)
>   2016-07-27 21:29:55,223 WARN  [DataStreamer for file /hbase/WALs/server2,16020,1469669327730/server2%2C16020%2C1469669327730.default.1469669334510 block BP-1601089490-xx.xx.xx.xx-1469276064635:blk_1073742337_1586] hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block BP-1601089490-xx.xx.xx.xx-1469276064635:blk_1073742337_1586 in pipeline xx.xx.xx.200:50010, xx.xx.xx.20:50010: bad datanode xx.xx.xx.200:50010
>   2016-07-27 21:29:55,247 WARN  [DataStreamer for file /hbase/WALs/server2,16020,1469669327730/server2%2C16020%2C1469669327730.default.1469669334510 block BP-1601089490-xx.xx.xx.xx-1469276064635:blk_1073742337_1586] hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to replace a bad datanode on the existing pipeline due to no more good datanodes being available to try. (Nodes: current=[xx.xx.xx.20:50010], original=[xx.xx.xx.20:50010]). The current failed datanode replacement policy is DEFAULT, and a client may configure this via 'dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy' in its configuration.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.findNewDatanode(DFSOutputStream.java:969)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.addDatanode2ExistingPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1035)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.setupPipelineForAppendOrRecovery(DFSOutputStream.java:1184)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.processDatanodeError(DFSOutputStream.java:933)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:487)

Soon after，there no HRegionServer alive.
I had configure hdfs-site.xml with

```
<property> 
<name>dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.enable</name>
<value>true</value> </property> 
<property> <name>dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.policy</name> 
<value>NEVER</value> 
</property>
```

it still log this WARN,I had google it,but nothing to do.So, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

It may due to the timeout property
in hbase-site.xml

```
<property>  
  <name>dfs.client.socket-timeout</name>  
  <value>600000</value>  
</property>
```

it's 600s but in hdfs-site.xml I dont set it may be default setting.
so the sync is different.
resolve：
set the same property in hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>  
  <name>dfs.client.socket-timeout</name>  
  <value>600000</value>  
</property>
```

than it work...

reference --> http://blog.csdn.net/zhaokunwu/article/details/7336892